# Confused with process IDs in Python 3

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, process

I have a `main.py` as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import os
import subprocess

fs = './runner.py'
child_process = subprocess.Popen(
    '/usr/bin/python3 ' + fs,
    shell=True
)


print('main process pid', os.getpid())
print('sub process pid', child_process.pid)
time.sleep(10)
os.system('kill ' + str(child_process.pid))
```

And `runner.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import time

TIME_TO_CHECK_STATUS = 1


def init():
    pid = os.getpid()
    print('inside child process:')
    print(' --> pid: ', pid)
    def check():
        time.sleep(TIME_TO_CHECK_STATUS)
        check()
        return pid

    return check()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

Running main.py in terminal given following result:

[image]

Why id of child process we got from `main.py` is different from what we got from child process inside?

Answer (score 2):

You are running the script as `/usr/bin/python3 ./runner.py` i.e. as an argument to `/usr/bin/python3`, so the PID tree becomes:

- `main.py`: Parent: PID=16350
- `/usr/bin/python3`: Child (Subprocess) of `main.py`: PID=16351
- `runner.py`: Grandchild to `main.py`, child to `/usr/bin/python3`: PID=16352

You would get `runner.py` as child of `main.py` if you execute it directly (without running it as an argument to `/usr/bin/python3`):

```
child_process = subprocess.Popen('./runner.py', shell=True)
```

You need to make `runner.py` executable before executing it directly, obviously.

As an aside, try to use the `subprocess.run` wrapper instead of directly mucking around `subprocess.Popen` (and brothers).

Comment: I've tried .run(), but it occupies the main process so there is nothing print out, and it's being never killed.

Comment: @DongNguyen `run` API is a bit different from `Popen`. You should read the doc thoroughly to get it working to your need :)

Comment: even I chmod runner.py as executable script, and run it directly, it's still create another process id. However I understand the cause here and that can be resolved with a little trick.